# Why did I fail to build mariadb?

Tags: mysql, visual-studio-2010, database, make, build

The error message is as follows:

```
141>  Call Stack (most recent call first):
141>    D:/tmp/mariadb-5.5.27/bu/cmake_install.cmake:81 (INCLUDE)
141>
141>
141>  CMake Error at D:/tmp/mariadb-5.5.27/bu/plugin/semisync/cmake_install.cmak
e:38 (FILE):
141>    file INSTALL cannot find
141>    "D:/tmp/mariadb-5.5.27/bu/plugin/semisync/RelWithDebInfo/semisync_master
.dll".
141>  Call Stack (most recent call first):
141>    D:/tmp/mariadb-5.5.27/bu/cmake_install.cmake:83 (INCLUDE)
141>
141>
141>  CMake Error at D:/tmp/mariadb-5.5.27/bu/plugin/semisync/cmake_install.cmak
e:54 (FILE):
141>    file INSTALL cannot find
141>    "D:/tmp/mariadb-5.5.27/bu/plugin/semisync/RelWithDebInfo/semisync_slave.
dll".
141>  Call Stack (most recent call first):
141>    D:/tmp/mariadb-5.5.27/bu/cmake_install.cmake:83 (INCLUDE)
141>
141>
141>  CMake Error at D:/tmp/mariadb-5.5.27/bu/plugin/sql_errlog/cmake_install.cm
ake:38 (FILE):
141>    file INSTALL cannot find
141>    "D:/tmp/mariadb-5.5.27/bu/plugin/sql_errlog/RelWithDebInfo/sql_errlog.dl
l".
141>  Call Stack (most recent call first):
141>    D:/tmp/mariadb-5.5.27/bu/cmake_install.cmake:84 (INCLUDE)
141>
141>
141>  CMake Error at D:/tmp/mariadb-5.5.27/bu/plugin/win_auth_client/cmake_insta
ll.cmake:38 (FILE):
141>    file INSTALL cannot find
141>    "D:/tmp/mariadb-5.5.27/bu/plugin/win_auth_client/RelWithDebInfo/authenti
cation_windows_client.dll".
141>  Call Stack (most recent call first):
141>    D:/tmp/mariadb-5.5.27/bu/cmake_install.cmake:85 (INCLUDE)
141>
141>
141>  CMake Error at D:/tmp/mariadb-5.5.27/bu/sql/cmake_install.cmake:38 (FILE):

141>    file INSTALL cannot find
141>    "D:/tmp/mariadb-5.5.27/bu/sql/RelWithDebInfo/mysqld.exe".
141>  Call Stack (most recent call first):
141>    D:/tmp/mariadb-5.5.27/bu/cmake_install.cmake:100 (INCLUDE)
141>
141>
    ...
141>    "D:/tmp/mariadb-5.5.27/bu/plugin/win_auth_client/RelWithDebInfo/authenti
cation_windows_client.dll".
141>  Call Stack (most recent call first):
141>    D:/tmp/mariadb-5.5.27/bu/cmake_install.cmake:85 (INCLUDE)
141>
141>
141>  CMake Error at D:/tmp/mariadb-5.5.27/bu/sql/cmake_install.cmake:38 (FILE):

141>    file INSTALL cannot find
141>    "D:/tmp/mariadb-5.5.27/bu/sql/RelWithDebInfo/mysqld.exe".
141>  Call Stack (most recent call first):
141>    D:/tmp/mariadb-5.5.27/bu/cmake_install.cmake:100 (INCLUDE)
141>
141>
141>EXEC : CPack error : Error when generating package: MySQL
141>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\Microsoft.CppCommon.target
s(113,5): error MSB3073: 命令“setlocal
141>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\Microsoft.CppCommon.target
s(113,5): error MSB3073: cd D:\tmp\mariadb-5.5.27\bu
141>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\Microsoft.CppCommon.target
s(113,5): error MSB3073: if %errorlevel% neq 0 goto :cmEnd
141>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\Microsoft.CppCommon.target
s(113,5): error MSB3073: D:
141>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\Microsoft.CppCommon.target
s(113,5): error MSB3073: if %errorlevel% neq 0 goto :cmEnd
141>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\Microsoft.CppCommon.target
s(113,5): error MSB3073: C:\tools\cmake28\bin\cpack.exe -C RelWithDebInfo --conf
ig ./CPackConfig.cmake
141>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\Microsoft.CppCommon.target
s(113,5): error MSB3073: if %errorlevel% neq 0 goto :cmEnd
141>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\Microsoft.CppCommon.target
s(113,5): error MSB3073: :cmEnd
141>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\Microsoft.CppCommon.target
s(113,5): error MSB3073: endlocal & call :cmErrorLevel %errorlevel% & goto :cmDo
ne
141>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\Microsoft.CppCommon.target
s(113,5): error MSB3073: :cmErrorLevel
141>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\Microsoft.CppCommon.target
s(113,5): error MSB3073: exit /b %1
141>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\Microsoft.CppCommon.target
s(113,5): error MSB3073: :cmDone
141>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\Microsoft.CppCommon.target
s(113,5): error MSB3073: if %errorlevel% neq 0 goto :VCEnd
141>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\Microsoft.CppCommon.target
```

Answer (score 3):

It looks like the compile failed, as the error is about binaries that cannot be installed because they do not exist.

However, it is impossible to guess what the original error is, as the provided output is incomplete - most likely the real problem occured earlier.

Comment: so do you need the whole output? that could be a large file:(